# Flutter app/build.gradle error but app works

Tags: flutter

The file build.gradle in the app folder shows an error(shown in the attached image). But when I run the app it works just fine. Should I be concerned about it?
[image]

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No You don't have to worry about it.

If you open your `Android` project in Android studio then this errors will gone.

To open `Android` module in Android studio.

> Right click on your project => Flutter => Select Open Android module in Android Studio.

**Update**

You can enable the "Enable code completion, navigation, etc. for Java/Kotlin." from preferences.

> Prefrences/Settings => Languages and Frameworks => Flutter => Below a Experiments tab.

This feature is still in experimental.